# Oozie Console HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP with Java1.8 latest Version

Tags: jsp, java-8, tomcat6, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I have installed Oozie 4.1.0 using cloudera repo. When I am trying to access Ozzie web console, I am getting below error after upgrading java to Jdk1.8.0_102.
I am getting the error when Oozie installed on lower version of java and run on jdk1.8.0_102.

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP

type Exception report

message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:161)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:155)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:160)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:155)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:160)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:155)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:160)
    org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 logs.

Catalina.out trace.

```
SEVERE: Exception processing TLD META-INF/taglib.tld in JAR at resource path /usr/lib/oozie/libserver/jersey-server-1.9.jar in context /oozie
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [[dtd]] with public ID [-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN], system ID [http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] and base URI [null] to a known, local entity.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.LocalResolver.resolveEntity(LocalResolver.java:151)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.EntityResolver2Wrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:408)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:320)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/oozie/libserver/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Sep 28, 2016 2:58:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 28, 2016 2:58:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
SEVERE: Exception processing TLD META-INF/taglib.tld in JAR at resource path /usr/lib/oozie/libserver/jersey-server-1.9.jar in context 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [[dtd]] with public ID [-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN], system ID [http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] and base URI [null] to a known, local entity.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.LocalResolver.resolveEntity(LocalResolver.java:151)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.EntityResolver2Wrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:408)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:320)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Sep 28, 2016 2:58:45 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-11000
Sep 28, 2016 2:58:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7008 ms
```

Comment: I am not sure, but i think tomcat6 is not java8 compatible.

Comment: Look in your logfiles, maybe you get more informations

Comment: SEVERE: Exception processing TLD META-INF/taglib.tld in JAR at resource path /usr/lib/oozie/libserver/jersey-server-1.9.jar in context 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [[dtd]] with public ID [-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN], 
system ID [http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] and base URI [null] to a known, local entity.

Comment: SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)

Comment: Above are the logs in catalina.out. @Jens

Comment: Add the complete Stacktrace to your question

Comment: @Jens can you please have look now

Comment: Do you have the `jsp-api.jar` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes @Jens jsp-api.jar is aaded in classpath

Comment: @Jens I am geeting above error during java8 up-gradation to 1.8.0_102. Oozie installed on lower java version and at run time java upgraded to 1.8_0_102, I am getting above error. Can you help